# Finding if $\sum\frac{1}{2+3^{-k}}$ divergent or convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would one find if the following series is divergent or convergent.

$$\sum\frac{1}{2+3^{-k}}$$

I did the following

$$\sum\frac{1}{2+3^{-k}}<\sum\frac{1}{3^{-k}}$$

But I am not sure what test I should use the only ones I know are limit comparison and basic comparison test.

But what should I do.

Comment: The terms do not go to $0$.

Comment: How about $\frac1{2+3^{-k}} \ge \frac13$?

Comment: Hint: $\forall k\gt 0,\frac 13\le \frac 1{2+3^{-k}}\le \frac 12$...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Hint:* $$\lim_{k \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2+3^{-k}} = \frac12.$$

Comment: It goes to 1/2 but how?

Comment: $3^{-k}\to 0\text{ as }k\to \infty$

Comment: oh yes I forget because it is $\frac{3}{1^k}$ k approach infinity

Comment: So it is divergent because when you take the limit as k approach infinity it is not zero.

Comment: Yes @FernandoMartinez: the limit of the series' **sequence** is not zero and thus the series cannot converge...

Answer (score 1):

It's of course divergent because the item of a convergent series must approach $0$ as $n\to \infty$.